# Can I say that a major "have" teaching positions?

Tags: word-usage

Example:

> Her major, Spanish, have very few teaching positions in my city.

Is using "have" strange in a case like this? (Like, how can a major have teaching positions?). If so, what's a better alternative?

Comment: *Had* means *had, was in possession of, had been in possession of*. However, you don't use that word in the question title. Which are you asking about? (*Have* is not correct for a singular subject in indicative mood.)

Comment: As I said, *have* is **definitely wrong.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In my city, there are very few open teaching positions in the subject in which she majored, Spanish.*

Answer (score 1):

> There are very few teaching positions available for Spanish majors, like her, in my city.

"Have" indicates possession rather than availability or the potential to do something, which is more what you're looking for (since you have to apply for jobs, rather than them just being given to you on the basis of your degree).

Answer (score 1):

> Her major, Spanish, have very few teaching positions in my city.

Remove the bracketed area, and you get 'Her major *have* very few teaching positions in my city'. This is certainly incorrect. In this case, the singular `major` should be coupled with the third-person singular simple present indicative `has`.

Although... others have noted that 'have' may be the incorrect word when referring to something for which you must apply. If you really want to keep 'have' though, I recommend changing 'positions' to 'opportunities'.